# Getting the lowest date from foreach

Tags: php

I want to get lowest date from following for each.

```
foreach ($check_date AS $value) {
    if ($result[$i][$j]['date'] == $value['date'] ) {

        if ($value['date_type'] == '1') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = -555;
        } else if ($value['date_type'] == '2') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = -666;
        }

    }

    if ($j < $limit - 1 && $result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] == $value['date']  ) {
        print_r($result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] );
        if ($value['date_type'] == '1') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = 0;
        } else if ($value['date_type'] == '2') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`print_r($result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] );` printes 2016-03-212016-03-22. I want to get 2016-03-21 from this.

How to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the lowest date only on the if where you use `print_r`. So the code below is just for this case. 
You can have a variable where to store this min date and init it before if. And on each loop to check if that is not inited or is smaller.
So the code should be like this:

```
$min_date = false;
foreach ($check_date AS $value) {
    if ($result[$i][$j]['date'] == $value['date'] ) {

        if ($value['date_type'] == '1') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = -555;
        } else if ($value['date_type'] == '2') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = -666;
        }

    }

    if ($j < $limit - 1 && $result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] == $value['date']  ) {
        if($min_date === false || $min_date > $result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] ) {
           $min_date = $result[$i][$j + 1]['date'];
        }
        print_r($result[$i][$j + 1]['date'] );
        if ($value['date_type'] == '1') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = 0;
        } else if ($value['date_type'] == '2') {
            $result[$i][$j]['value'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
echo $min_date; // Here you will have the lowest date.
```